# How I start this Python-Project from Github?

Tags: python, github, pip

I started with Python and looked at some tutorial and downloaded Python 3.6. Now I wanted to look at some sample projects and came across at this LoL-project. But unfortunately I have no idea how to start this project. I installed it `pip install riotwatcher`  and next comes the section "Using It"
There is a code. Do I have to add that somewhere or what do I have to do here? I'm just a beginner. Can someone help me? :) Thx

Project-link: https://github.com/pseudonym117/Riot-Watcher

Comment: There is no program to use, that library is an API that *you* can use to write a program. You'd write some python code that will `import riotwatcher` then do whatever, then you can call it from the command line, for example `python your_program.py`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a project, It's a module/library. Here's an explanation about what they are: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html. You use the library to get the data from LoL, like how it says in the **Using It** section:

```
from riotwatcher import RiotWatcher #Imports the library so you can use it

watcher = RiotWatcher('<your-api-key>') #RiotWatcher is a constructor in the library

my_region = 'na1'

me = watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, 'pseudonym117') #calls a function on the watcher object
print(me)
my_ranked_stats = watcher.league.positions_by_summoner(my_region, me['id']) #a function of the library
print(my_ranked_stats)
```

You are supposed to install the library then call these functions ^ to do things with it. The library isn't a project, you use it to make your projects. Try to find an example project, since you don't need too many external libraries until you've mastered the basics, plus OOP is a little complex to start out with. If you want to learn more about the objects and OOP from the sample code check this out: https://python.swaroopch.com/oop.html, but I would recommend starting with the basics try this site out for some example projects: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-code-examples